# The quality or state of being relevant to the subject under discussion

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

I'm trying to nominalize the word "on-topic". The closest I have come is "on-topicness", but I do not think that is a real world, nor have I been able to find anything that suggests it is.

Sample sentence:

> The **on-topicness** of the post was amplified by the edit.

What is a term describing the quality or state of being relevant to the subject under discussion?

Comment: Your own term *relevance* seems to fit the bill.

Comment: Yes, *relevance*, *relevancy*, *pertinence*, *applicability*, *suitability*,...

Comment: I understand now that my search queries were too specific. I was too focused on the word "on-topic" and missed the general relation to "relevance". I'm sorry if users find that this question shows a lack of research effort or is not useful. I promise that I did search, just obviously not for the right thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to *relevance* itself (as already pointed out), ***pertinence*** works here (it is actually synonymous with *relevance*).

ODO:

> **[pertinence](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pertinence)**
>   *NOUN*
>
> See **[pertinent](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pertinent)**.
>
> ‘This concern reflects the pertinence of these issues to student
>   life.’
>
> **[pertinent](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pertinent)**
>   *ADJECTIVE*
>
> Relevant or applicable to a particular matter; apposite:
>   ‘she asked
>   me a lot of very pertinent questions’

Answer (score 3):

You could use the word **relevance**.

> The relevance of the post was amplified by the edit.

Definition:

> [relevance](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/relevance)
>
> relation to the matter at hand
>
> (also: [relevant](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/relevant))
>
> relating to a subject in an appropriate way

Answer (score 0):

**germane**

> being at once relevant and appropriate
>
> https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/germane

Comment: Do you mean *germaneness*?